# I am trying to write a new file and return the file size and the output should be 31 in this example but i am getting 0 .(using python)

Tags: python

```
import os
def create_python_script(filename):
    comments = "# Start of a new Python program"
    with open(filename, "w") as file:
        file.write(comments)
        filesize = os.path.getsize(filename)
    return(filesize)

print(create_python_script("program.py")
```

Comment: you're missing an ending ```)``` on your print line

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are reading the file size too soon. Move it outside the `with`

The below outputs

```
0
31
```

Code

```
import os
def create_python_script(filename):
    comments = "# Start of a new Python program"
    with open(filename, "w") as file:
        file.write(comments)
        filesize = os.path.getsize(filename)
    return(filesize)

def create_python_script2(filename):
    comments = "# Start of a new Python program"
    with open(filename, "w") as file:
        file.write(comments)
    filesize = os.path.getsize(filename)
    return(filesize)

print(create_python_script("program.py"))
print(create_python_script2("program.py"))
```

The contents of the file aren't "flushed" out to the file until the file is closed. Since you are using a context mananger `with` , the file is closed when you leave the context manager.

Comment: I missed the code indentations i am still learning thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

You have to close the file before getting the size so the changes will be reflected into the disk. The code will be:

```python
import os
def create_python_script(filename):
    comments = "# Start of a new Python program"
    with open(filename, "w") as file:
        file.write(comments)
    filesize = os.path.getsize(filename)
    return(filesize)

print(create_python_script("program.py"))
```

Comment: I missed the code indentations i am still learning thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

System get file size when file closed not during opening state.

you could try to get filesize at outscope of `with` clause:

```py
import os
def create_python_script(filename):
    comments = "# Start of a new Python program"
    with open(filename, "w") as file:
        file.write(comments)

    filesize = os.path.getsize(filename)
    return(filesize)

print(create_python_script("program.py"))
```

it prints `31` :)

Comment: I missed the code indentations i am still learning thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

All above answers mentioning context manager scope is correct for sure.

But sometimes, you actually need to know/estimate file size while writing – i.e., when chunking writes or rotating logs.

In this case, you can use [`file.tell()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html#io.TextIOBase.tell), which gives you stream position in bytes.